# How to avoid stack creep with callbacks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, stack

The following JavaScript code emulates retrying an HTTP request as often as the user presses the OK button on a `window.alert`. It can be seen that the stack trace dumped to the console increases in length linearly with the number of times the request retried.

To run this, use `chromium --user-data-dir=/tmp/"$(uuidgen -r)" --disable-web-security` and navigate to an HTML file that just contains the bare minimum `<html>` `<body>` and `<script>` tags. Disabling web security is required for the HTTP request to succeed, otherwise the default CORS policy will block it.

Basically, the question is: how can this linear stack creep be prevented?

```
function f() {
    console.log("C");
    fetch('http://swapi.co/api/films').
        then(function (response) {
            console.log("D");
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log("E");
            console.log(response);
            console.trace();
            window.alert("more?");
            f();
        });
}

function ignition() {
    console.log("B");
    f();
}

console.log("A");
window.onload = ignition;
```

Comment: Well, don't create it in the first place.  ;-)  The simplest way I can see to fix that is to replace the recursive call to `f()` with `setTimeout(f, 0)`.  Is there some reason that won't do for you?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Tried that, at least in Chromium browser `setTimeout` will copy (or more likely, link) the current stack. So the linear behavior is observed all the same and `f` does not get a fresh start that way.

Comment: Ahh, well, that *used to* work.  I'm not surprised it doesn't now, as fixing it usually makes for better debugging.  As to your problem, if you really do have that deep a stack, do you really want to hide it?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Well, I want to not have such a deep stack, then there won't be a need to hide it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution; it's not ideal as it involves `setInterval` but it's workable and avoids stack creep. It can only do straight retry; this solution cannot maintain any extra state between invocations of the queued functions, though it wouldn't be that hard to add.

```
const self_queue = [];

function self_append(fun) {
    self_queue.push(fun);
}

setInterval((function() {
    if (self_queue.length > 0) {
        const fun = self_queue.shift();

        fun(fun);
    }
}), 100);

function ajax(url, fun) {
    self_append((function (self_fun) {
      // ...
      // do the HTTP fetch, on success call fun(json)
      // on retry, do:
      self_append(self_fun);
      // ....
    }));
}
```